# Charging Two Parallel LiPo4 12v 20ah batteries at the same time

Tags: battery-charging

I am getting conflicting information from the manufacturer. My understanding is that If I charge batteries wired in Serial, they can be charged about 5 times as a unit but then should be charged separately every 5th or 6th time to balance them. If I charge batteries together in Parallel, they DO NOT need to be charged separately charged (albeit, balancing them at the beginning of use is wise and good). I now have someone saying that whether they are charged in serial or parallel they need to be charged separately every 5th time.

What is the best practice and what is acceptable? Thanks.

Comment: It should be OK to put them in parallel. People do it all the time. Ideally, though, you would have individual over-current protection for each cell (fuse or PTC). And ideally you would monitor the temperature of both cells (since you only have two, it should be feasible) to make sure that A, they are the approximately the same and B neither cell is too hot.

Comment: In practical terms, it is **not okay to parallel packs** unless you can guarantee a matching state of charge.  Permanent assemblies are one thing; assembling for the purpose of charging is **generally impermissible**, because if you accidentally connect a more charged pack to a less charged one, now you are charging one pack from the other *without a charge controller*.

Comment: The packs are in a permanent assembly. I could set it up to have two separate batteries feeding the load and when one is depleted, manually toggle switch to the other. As well, I could also charge the A battery when using the B battery and vice versa, through a switch. Is there a BMS that could handle this if wired in parallel?

Comment: To clarify, I agree with Chris Stratton. My comment was intended to apply to permanent assembly.

Answer (score 0):

If you charge in parallel, it forces them to share the same voltage, so they are automatically balanced. However, their individual currents are not monitored. If one battery is going bad, then the other one may be getting overcharged by accepting twice the termination current before the end of the constant voltage charge. Whether it's worth individual charging to catch this event is debatable.

They **MUST** be balanced in voltage before connecting them together to charge in parallel. Connecting two high current batteries like LiPos with different voltages is a sure fire way to get a fire. The simplest way to do this is to connect them together with a resistor to limit the current until they are balanced.

If you charge in series, then any imbalance in charge or discharge efficiency or leakage will definitely unbalance the batteries. Whether you can wait as long as 6 cycles is debatable.

Comment: Imbalance is not just a problem during charge, it's a problem if you connect packs of different charge together in preparation for charge.  It's a bad idea: **don't do it!**.

Comment: SO in general (in general), batteries should be balanced as close to optimum as possible BEFORE connecting them in parallel in the very beginning. The batteries are in a permanent install, but I can design it so you have to charge the batteries separately—you can use one while charging the other. They are connected and disconnected using a Cam Rotary. I have a switch position for Off, Internal Supply (the two 20ah batteries in parallel), External Supply (any 12v DC input from another 12v battery or AC 12v power supply) and Charge—to charge the batteries.

Comment: (Continued)  I could add a switch position to give Charge Battery A and Charge Battery B to isolate them for charging.  I could also add a Relay to switch batteries when the voltage gets too low on one. Thanks for the input.